Сессии в телеграме
Была одна сессия на пк, которой пользовался, потом создал вторую сессию с второго телефона вот так:
from pyrogram import Client
api_id = 111
api_hash = "111"
session_file = "my_tg_session"
app = Client(session_file, api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash)
with app:
    print("Отправка кода для подтверждения...")
    app.start()
    print(f"Сессия сохранена в файл {session_file}.session")

Первая сессия слетела и не работает. В чём может быть причина?
